# appending data to existing dataframe without creating a new object in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

i have 2 data frames
df1 has 3 columns cust_id,first name, last name
df2 has 1 column cust_id

for each row in df2, i want to extract data from df1 and append to df3,
df3 has 3 columns cust_id,first name, last name

i tried this

```
for i,r in df2.iterrows():
    data = df1[df1[cust_id]==r]
    pandas.concat(data,df3)
```

> the above is giving me error: first argument must be an iterable of
> pandas objects, you passed an object of type "DataFrame"

i tried other as

```
for i,r in df2.iterrows():
     data = df1[df1[cust_id]==r]
     df3.append(data)
```

> this code is creating a new dataframe other than df3

how can i achieve this without creating a new object?

Comment: What are the columns of df3?

Comment: they are the same columns as df1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error couldn't be cleaner: As you can see in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) `pd.concat` receives an iterable and other aditional parameters, but you are passing a dataframe(`data`) as first parameter and a another dataframe(`df3`) as another parameter, instead of an iterable with the dataframes to concat, so you should change `pandas.concat(data,df3)` to `pandas.concat([data,df3])`. And as a suggestion, to avoid the usage of `iterrows`, you can try with `pd.Series.isin`:

```
pd.concat([df1[df1['cust_id'].isin(df2['cust_id'])],df3])
```